# Customize Zoom in/out button in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I am trying to customize zoom control (+/-), so it should appear in the right side like Google maps (https://www.google.com/maps/)

I tried to add `float:right;` but it didn't work.

From the CSS file :

```css
/* zoom control */

.leaflet-control-zoom-in,
.leaflet-control-zoom-out {
  font: bold 18px 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
  text-indent: 1px;
  }
.leaflet-control-zoom-out {
  font-size: 20px;
  }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-in {
  font-size: 22px;
  }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-out {
  font-size: 24px;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsy7v/1/

Comment: Because I have seen many questions about customizing the position of controls in Leaflet, here is a simple CSS approach: Use .leaflet-top { padding-top: 50px; }. This will offset both the zoom control and the layer control down. You can target them individually by using their positions.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Your zoom in/out controls are wrapped with absolutely positioned element with `left:0` (due to .leaflet-left class), so `float:left` wouldn't help, you could align it to right by overriding `left:0` by `right:0`, or changing `.leaflet-left` class to `.leaflet-right`

But more correct way would be to use provided api.

```
//disable zoomControl when initializing map (which is topleft by default)
var map = L.map("map", {
    zoomControl: false
    //... other options
});

//add zoom control with your options
L.control.zoom({
     position:'topright'
}).addTo(map);
```

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/hsy7v/3/)

api reference for the library you use can be found [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html)

Comment: But it's limited ! I'd like to control the position ( position:'topright') but padding-top 30 px ? How can I do that ?

Comment: as I said, your control are wrapped in absolutely positioned element, e.g. in case of 'topright' it would have .leafleft-right class, so you can just add something like `top:30px` to it in css

Answer (score 60):

Currently you can use:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  zoomControl: true
});
map.zoomControl.setPosition('topright');
```

Comment: I turned to use the same, few weeks later. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Actually this deletes the control and re-creates it with the correct position. The accepted answer is better. But this answer helped me understand the API.

Comment: Any idea why you can't chain these together?

Answer (score 1):

if your using leaflet in angular don't forget about ::ngdeep without this styles do not apply

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).