# Change the default position of zoom control in leaflet map of Shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I am using Shiny app to create leaflet map, but want to change the default position of zoom control from `topleft` to `topright`.

R `leaflet` package sets the default position as `topleft` in the source codes.

Following this question: [Customize Zoom in/out button in leaflet.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926512), we can use `map.zoomControl.setPosition('topright');` to change position of zoom control.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  zoomControl: true
});
map.zoomControl.setPosition('topright');
```

Could I create a R function to set new position of `zoomControl`? For example,

```
zoomControlPosition <- function(map, position = 'topleft') {
    # New codes add here
}
```

I guess it involves some `js`, but I have no experience of `js`. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figure out how to change the position of `zoomControl`. You can find this feature from my fork of leaflet package: https://github.com/byzheng/leaflet/commit/fdf9fb159adbc0e36cc2bd7d7b33c72c17c468f6

[image]

This is an minimum example to use it:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%

      zoomControlPosition('topright')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This might be a silly question, but how do I access your `zoomControlPosition` function from the link you provided?

Comment: It seems my pull request has not be merged into leaflet package. You can find it from my fork: https://github.com/byzheng/leaflet

Comment: You've deleted your fork, Bangyou. Can you tell us how you created the zoomControlPosition function, please?

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>%
    htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x) {
        L.control.zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(this)
    }") %>%
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I haven't tried it I think Bangyou gave you an answer that exactly answers your question.

I'd still like to share my approach to this issue for two reasons:

- It gives easy flexibility to modify your zoomControl in many ways (working only in R)
- It doesn't modify the leaflet package, so your probably good with all upcoming leaflet releases.

The approach is to customise the zoomcontrol with actionButtons.

In the server

- Keep track of current map view in reactive values. (I use this for more than just zoom control)
- Set the view (setView) up or down when the respective action button is pressed.

Add to server.R

```
# Zoom control - zoom out
observeEvent(input$map_zoom_out ,{
  leafletProxy("map") %>% 
    setView(lat  = (input$map_bounds$north + input$map_bounds$south) / 2,
            lng  = (input$map_bounds$east + input$map_bounds$west) / 2,
            zoom = input$map_zoom - 1)
})
# Zoom control - zoom in
observeEvent(input$map_zoom_in ,{
  leafletProxy("map") %>% 
    setView(lat  = (input$map_bounds$north + input$map_bounds$south) / 2,
            lng  = (input$map_bounds$east + input$map_bounds$west) / 2,
            zoom = input$map_zoom + 1)
})
```

I like to add absolutepanels in the UI with actionButtons, but place the buttons where you like.

In ui.R add:

```
absolutePanel(
  top = "auto", left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = 20,
  width = "auto", height = "auto",
  actionButton("map_zoom_in", "+"),
  actionButton("map_zoom_out", "-")
)
```

This allows you to change the default position and choose any position. Don't forget to disable the standard zoom control in the server with

```
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE))
```

Hope it's valuable.

Best,
Jiddu Alexander