# Leaflet controls overlay navbarMenu in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

In a `shiny` `navbarPage` app the `leaflet` +- control overlays the `navbarMenu` content making it hard to read (the user might have to resize the browser window to be able to read the menu). Is this a bug? Is there a way to move the +- control into the background?

[image]

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(NULL,
  navbarMenu("Menu",
    tabPanel("Menu Item 1", leafletOutput("map")),
    tabPanel("Menu Item 2"),
    tabPanel("Menu Item 3")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: maybe you can change the position of your zoom control. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543814/change-the-default-position-of-zoom-control-in-leaflet-map-of-shiny-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick to move the +- control behind the dropdown menu by changing the `z-index` value of the +- control.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(NULL,
  navbarMenu("Menu",
    tabPanel("Menu Item 1", leafletOutput("map")),
    tabPanel("Menu Item 2"),
    tabPanel("Menu Item 3")
  ),
  tags$head(tags$style(".leaflet-top {z-index:999!important;}"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```